# How to know that Catwoman side mission is done?

Tags: batman-arkham-city

I finished Batman Arkham City main mission and now playing Catwoman side mission which it is, get her loot back.

There is read bar to indicate how much jewels have you get back.

If I'm not wrong, the bar is already full and Catwoman said something but I didn't focus enough as I was in the middle of a fight.

Any indicator whether the mission is done or not yet?

Answer (score 2):

When you pause the game as Catwoman, there will be a bar in the upper right corner, listing a number out of 16, ie. 11/16.

Answer (score 0):

In the statistics section of the main view of the game, there is a percentage indicator of the the progress of each side mission and the whole game.